# Visual Studio crash when Deploy SSRS Report

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Using Visual Studio 2013, when try to **deploy** the Report, the session Crash
I attach the messages

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

[image]

by Event Viewer

[image]

I already followed this way - BUT the issue has not been resolved.

http://www.wkcerp.com/ax/crash-or-hang-during-ax-project-or-report-build-visual-studio-2013-ax-r3-cu8/

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you deploy the report from the AOT or the Powershell? Have you tried reinstalling the reporting extensions for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here, and in my case the problem was a faulty installation of the **SQL ADMd.Net components**.  Try and reinstall those.
There is a DLL, named **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdmomdClient.dll**, which could not be found in my case.  This caused a stackoverflow exception in my case.  The admin reinstalled those components, and the DLL got installed, too.  Deploying reports is now possible :).

I figured this out by attaching one VS instance with debugging enabled to another VS instance, with which I tried to deploy reports.
Also, I had to enable debugging for .NET Code in the settings.

I set a breakpoint at the function

```
Mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.TypeHandle.GetTypeByName
```

And that's where I noticed, that the same block functions were called over and over, trying to load the DLL, but not being able to find it.  It is the `nLoad` function.
(https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,460c8abec12d58cd).
This eventally caused the Exception, and the exception code **0xc00000fd**, which is a Stackoverflow exception.

I can't post images here, but I hope it's still understandable.

Best regards,
Jannik.